# jest.mock() only works within jestSetup.js

Tags: react-native, testing, mocking, jestjs

I have jest mocks (mocked functions, modules and components) in my `jestSetup.js` file (pointed to from `package.json`), and I also have mocks in individual test files, including unit tests and snapshot tests.

In my individual snapshot tests, the mocks do not work anymore (since upgrading to RN 0.56) - the mocks exist (I can console.log them) but when the snapshot tests are run, the mocked functions are not called - instead the "real" functions are called. This is NOT the case for mocks defined the SAME way but placed in `jestSetup.js` - the snapshots call the mocked functions as expected when they are defined in `jestSetup.js`.

I have moved as many mocks as possible to jestSetup.js but unfortunately some tests require the functions to be unmocked (e.g. unit tests) so this cannot fix all my new errors.

Can anyone see a way to either enabled my mocks to work in individual test files or otherwise?

Profile.test.js

```
import 'react-native';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import React from 'react';
import sinon from 'sinon';

jest.mock(
  '../../src/components/common/ProfilePicture/StarredPicture/StarredPicture',
  () => () => { return ''; },
);

test('renders correctly', () => {
  const stub = sinon.stub(console, 'error');
  const tree = renderer.create(<Profile />).toJSON();
  const tree = renderer
    .create(<Profile />)
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  // call count is one to reflect one required proptypes.
  expect(stub.callCount).toEqual(1);
```

package.json

```
"jest": {
    "automock": false,
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./src/jestSetup",
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!@expo)/"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: This is a related issue on GitHub https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20508

Comment: Hi @Tom...did you manage to resolve this in the end? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @MDalt resolution is here! https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20508#issuecomment-410307465

Comment: Ah brilliant thanks. In case it gives anyone looking some ideas...my issue/fix was actually slightly different. I needed to add "jest-hoist" to "plugins" in .babelrc to ensure hoisting was working properly